# Auto-generate WebControls

Tags: .net, asp.net, reflection, code-generation, auto-generate

I want to generate .net code from a template so that it more rapid, so lazy developers (and I mean that in the nicest possible way!) don't have to write them in the IDE, compile them, etc...

I know I can roll my own tool which generates the code using reflection (by reading in some text file, etc), but I just wondered if there was an easier than starting from scratch since this is what ASP.NET basically does already; so is there anyway to leverage this?

E.g. to quote [Peter A. Bromberg](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/20030518.asp):

> Even an ASPX page with no code on it
>   gets turned into an instance of the
>   System.Web.UI.Page class. **The page is
>   parsed by the ASP.NET engine when it
>   is first requested**, and then its JIT
>   compiled version is cached in the
>   Temporary ASP.NET Files folder as long
>   as the application is running and the
>   .aspx page hasn't been changed.

Ideally I want to auto-generate WebControls, but examples of anything closely related will do.
C# Examples preferred also, but anything considered :)

Answer (score 0):

I watched a grok-talk where a team had used [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/ASP.NET) to auto-generate the markup. They had thousands of similar `GridViews` to generate markup for.

Comment: Thanks - certainly looks interesting.